# calculate the time Django

Tags: django, datetime, time

I want to calculate the time between the hottest modification of the table and the amendment that will be on the table in the future to calculate the speed of service to customers and I want to calculate how many customers were served at a certain time?

```
class Customer(models.Model):
customer_bank        = models.ForeignKey('Bank', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,related_name='coustmer_bank' ,null=True)
customer_branch      = models.ForeignKey('Branch', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,related_name='coustmer_branch',null=True)
booking_id           = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank= True)
identity_type        = models.ForeignKey('IdentityType',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,related_name='identity_type',null=True)
identity_or_passport_number   = models.CharField(max_length=20)
bank_account_no      = models.CharField(max_length=15)
Done                 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
booking_date_time    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
Entrance_date_time   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
```

how to do it ?

Comment: And which datetime field is what? Where is the time difference you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You need somewhat like `start_processing` and `end_processing` with `datetime` type.

Of course, you need additional hepler fields like `created_on`, `modified_on` with `auto_now_add=True` and `auto_now=True` respectively.

You could also calculate `processing_time` in minutes or seconds for very easy selects like: `Modelname.objects.filter(processing_time__gt=10)`